# Hadoop2.5.2 gets stuck on Running Job when I try to run pi-example on YARN

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm running Hadoop2.5.2 on 3 machines with Ubuntu Server 14.04

One is the namenode and resourcemanager with ip 192.168.3.1
Others are slaves running datanode and nodemanager with ip 192.168.3.102 and 192.168.3.104 respectively.

I can run start-hdfs.sh and start-yarn.sh without any errors. The website of HDFS and YARN works well, I can visit both website on my browser and see status of two slaves.

But when I try to run the example of mapreduce under `~/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce'` via `yarn jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.5.2.jar pi 14 1000` The process gets stuck on `INFO mapreduce.job: Running job: ...`

The website of yarn shows that there is one container on a slave and the state of application is accepted.

When I tpye 'jps' on the slave

```
20265 MRAppMaster
20351 Jps
19206 DataNode
20019 NodeManager
```

The syslog file on the slave:

```
INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8030
INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8030. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8030. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
...
```

It seems that the slave doesn't use the defalut RM ip address instead the real one on 192.168.3.1

Here is my configuration on the slaves:
**yarn-site.xml**

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>192.168.3.1</value>
</property> 
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
    <value>192.168.3.1:8032</value>
</property>  
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
    <value>192.168.3.1:8030</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
    <value>192.168.3.1:8031</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
    <value>192.168.3.1:8088</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
    <value>192.168.3.1:8033</value>
</property> 
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<configuration>

<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:///home/hduser/hdfs/namenode</value>
    <description>NameNode directory for namespace and transaction logs storage</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.permissions</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.use.datanode.hostname</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://192.168.3.1:8020</value>
    <description>NameNode URI</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
19 <configuration>
20 
21 <property>
22     <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
23     <value>yarn</value>
24     <description>Use YARN</description>
25 </property>
```

The configuration on master is almost same except **yarn-site.xml**

```
65 <property>
66     <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
67     <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
68 </property>
69 
70 <property>
71     <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
72     <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
73 </property>
```

And I Change the **yarn-env.sh**
`export YARN_CONF_DIR="${YARN_CONF_DIR:-$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/etc/hadoop}"`

**I don't change the /etc/hosts**

Does anyone know how can I fix it? Thanks

***if need other information just tell me. I'll update..***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out it myself.

I downloaded a new version of Hadoop-2.6.0 source code and built it on my own machine.

The configuration was same as the 2.5.2 version but it just work !

I think it's a better way to **start with the source code** instead of the built one.

Answer (score 0):

```
INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8030
INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8030. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8030. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
...
```

Its trying to connect to the resource manager. Seems like its not running.

Check the resource manager service.

Comment: The ResourceManager is running on my master 192.168.3.1

Comment: Seems like your job is not pointing to the correct IP of the resource manager. Are you reading the conf files from the correct location? Or try setting the resource manager location in JobConf.

Comment: I tried to modify yarn-env.sh to make the YARN_CONF_DIR point to he $HADOOP_YARN_HOME/etc/hadoop and add YARN_CONF_DIR to .bashrc. But this doen't work. And could you please be more specific on the setting of JobConf? I'm a beginner of Hadoop. Thank u very much